# Writing a valid test case for validating XMLs

Tags: unit-testing, xml, validation, junit

How would I write a unit test, say JUnit, for validating an XML file?

I have an application that creates a document as an XML file. In order to validate this XML structure, do I need to create an XML mock object and compare each of its elements against the ones in the 'actual' XML file?

**IF SO:** Then what is the best practice for doing so? e.g. would I use the XML data from the 'actual' XML file to create the mock object? etc.

**IF NOT:** What is a valid unit test?

Comment: for starter separate the xml part from the file io part if you can

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To validate an XML file, you first need an XML Schema Definition (XSD) that describes the structure of a valid XML document. You can find the specification for XSD files at [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/).

Going into how to build the XSD requires knowing how your XML should be structured.

For detailed information about the actual Java implementation of this, check out [What's the best way to validate an XML file against an XSD file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16054/848058) on StackOverflow.

Relevant code from that post:

```java
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.*;
...

URL schemaFile = new URL("http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd");
Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File("web.xml"));
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
try {
  validator.validate(xmlFile);
  System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
} catch (SAXException e) {
  System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
  System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Comment: So validating an XML only means to validate against its schema and not against a mock XML, correct?

Comment: You can do either, but I would recommend the validation using the schema. It will be more robust of a comparison than verifying the mock matches what you expect.

Comment: Beware that xsd can create a hyper rigid schema. Take the time to understand how schema changes will impact you with respect to forwards/backwards compatibility.